# Чтение id3v2 меток (APIC)

Tags: php, id3v2

Есть удаленный сервер, на котором лежит стопка `mp3` файлов. 
Необходимо прочитать не скачивая весь файл - только изображение `APIC`.

Я использовал библиотеку `getID3`, и вот написал такую функцию:

```
function PrintImage ($url) {
    $DefalteImage = '<span>NULL</span><br>';
    $Image = $DefalteImage; //если тег не существуем - то выводим пустую картинку
    global $ID3;
    $handle = @fopen($url, "rb");
    if (FALSE === $handle) {
        $Image = $DefalteImage; //не удалось прочитать файл - то выводим пустую картинку
    }
    else {
        $contents = fread($handle, 1024);
        fclose($handle); // загружаем начало файла для проверки наличия ID3v2 teg APIC

        if (stripos($contents, 'APIC')) { //если тег существуем - то продолжаем
            $handle = fopen($url, "rb");
            if (FALSE === $handle) {
                $Image = $DefalteImage; //если тег не существуем - то выводим пустую картинку
            }
            else {
                $i = 0;
                $contents = '';

                while (!feof($handle)) { // получаем кусок файла
                    $contents.= fread($handle, 8*1024);
                    $i++;
                    if ($i == 200) break;  //сколько блоков читаем (ГЛАВНЫЙ ВОПРОС, как определить заранее, сколько байт нужно скачать)
                }

                fclose($handle);

                $fp = fopen('temp.dat', 'w'); //записываем в ТЕМП файл
                fwrite($fp, $contents);
                fclose($fp);

                $data = $ID3->analyze('temp.dat');  //анализируем и выкачиваем картинку
                unlink('temp.dat');  //удаляем темп файл

                $Image = '<img width="100px" height="100px" src="data:'.$data['comments']['picture'][0]['image_mime'].';charset=utf-8;base64,'.base64_encode($data['comments']['picture'][0]['data']).'"><br>';
            }
        }
    }

    return $Image;
}
```

Данная библиотека позволяет читать только файлы на локальном хранилище. Поэтому мой алгоритм скачивает часть файла с сервера, сохраняет в файл `temp.dat` и потом уже библиотека читает картинку.

Возникла трудность в том, что не все изображения подгружаются, так как мне неизвестна длина фрейма `APIC`.

В интернете все перерыл, в том числе и [документацию](http://id3.org/id3v2.4.0-frames)

Как определить заранее длину блока APIC?